# Removing old contexts in IntelliJ deployment

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

Using the jetty plugin with intellij idea 10.5:

Deploying a new webapp picks up old wars since the IDE doesn't seem to clear old contexts (or have an eclipse WTP-like ide integration).  Is there a way to configure intellij so that Jetty will pick up the new wars being deployed?

Answer (score 1):

Thats just a bug, you may track it at the http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70197

As stated at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5304939#5304939:

> After more consideration we decided to
>   ALWAYS use the temporary folder to
>   deploy context files to. So artifacts
>   deployed from IDEA will NEVER be kept
>   between Jetty startups.
>
> Even more, we have decide to backport
>   this fix (actually committed to
>   master) into the 10.5.x stream.